Difference between progress 12.2 and 12.8 for the learning path
I've recently installed the trial version of progress OpenEdge 12.8 (I'm completely new to progress) and I'm going through the Basic OpenEdge Developer Learning Path and Certification Exam.
I've noticed however, that some screenshots and settings in the learning path don't correspond with what I see (the learning path mentions it's for the 12.2 version, which I don't think I can get a trial version off). I'm not sure if it's because they're different versions or because I've got the trial version or perhaps something else.
I would like some insight into this. Is the learning path a bit outdated (due to the difference between 12.2 and 12.8) or is it something else on my side?
I've tried to find if I missed something when installing, but I didn't notice anything.

I would recommend you reading through the release notes. That could give some ideas about what changed. A lot will be bug fixes and minor things.

I would expect that there will be some relatively minor differences as 12.2 was first released 3 or 4 years ago and 12.8 is the currently active release.
If the differences that you see are "material" and you have questions about them I would strongly suggest that you ask about them on the Progress Community website: https://community.progress.com That is going to be more appropriate for that sort of thing than posting questions on Stackoverflow.
